# Locking a format within a catalog

Tags: sas

I'm want to lock an individual format within a catalog but I'm not sure if there's a way without SAS/SHARE.  Here's some sample formats:

```
proc format ;
  picture testfmt1 low-high='000,000' (prefix='$');
  picture testfmt2 low-high='000,000' ;
run;
```

I can lock the entire catalog using the below code, but I only want to lock 1 of the formats within the catalog and I can't figure out the correct syntax nor find any specific examples of the syntax being used.  Code to lock entire catalog:

```
lock work.formats.catalog;
lock work.formats.catalog clear;
```

I do NOT have SAS/SHARE but the documentation *seems* to say it is required to lock a single entry.  I'm not all that familiar with the terminology, hence the confusion: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001517609.htm

The above documentation says that the syntax to lock an entry is:

```
LOCK libref<.member-name<.member-type | .entry-name.entry-type>> <LIST | QUERY | SHOW | CLEAR>;
```

It looks like the pipe symbol is saying the syntax I want to use is `libref.entry-name.entry-type;` but I've tried all the combinations I can think of with no luck.

Strangely, the below code runs although I'm not sure what it's doing as it doesn't appear to be valid syntax:

```
lock work.formats.catalog.format;
```

Any clarifications on what can and can't be done and the correct syntax would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, row-level locking is not supported in any environment in SAS without SAS/SHARE (see [this discussion on sascommunity](https://communities.sas.com/message/17704) for example).  That's basically what this would be (catalog being equivalent to a dataset, so a catalog entry is basically a row or set of rows).

Assuming your goal was to have a set of formats users must use and may not edit, one option would be to have a master format catalog that was entirely locked, and stored in a shared location, and then allow users to customize formats into another format catalog.  Then set precedence using `fmtsearch` such that the locked format catalog got precedence.

```
options fmtsearch=(master work user library);
```

`work` and `library` must be explicitly listed in here to avoid them getting precedence by default.

Comment: Ahh - thinking of a catalog like a dataset makes things much clearer, thanks.  The goal was to prevent 2 different jobs on the same machine (1 reading, 1 writing) from trying to access the same format at the same time.  I have an ugly workaround I can use that will solve the problem, was just looking for a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: @RobertPenridge  Ah, interesting.  It's probably worth a post on communities and/or SAS-L, in that case; I'm certainly not an expert on this kind of thing.